# How to bulk insert data in Djnago without providing fields to model

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models

How to bulk insert data with only providing dictionary key and not worry about manually providing fields and type of fields in models.py

What I have to do right now:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Info(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

**Outout:**

```
name | email    
Jon  | j@g.com
```

**mongodb collection**

what I want without using fields and assigning more than 20-30 fields:

```
name | email | fname | lname | cellNum | add | age | height | etc...
```

for example using mongoClient to bulk insert data without providing fields

```
data = {x:x, y:y, z:z}
collection.insert_one(data)
collection.insert_many([data,...])
```